# Why do I get different results when using 'hasattr' function on the class and its object for the same attribute?

Tags: python

When I execute this code:

```
class cls :
    A=1
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=2
        
obj=cls()

print(hasattr(cls,'A'))
print(hasattr(cls,'a'))

print(hasattr(obj,'A'))
print(hasattr(obj,'a'))
```

I get this output:

```
True
False
True
True
```

Everything is clear to me except for the second line. Why do I get `False` when I execute the `hasattr` function on the *class* while I got `True` when using it with the *object* for the same attribute?

Comment: Because it's an instance attribute not a class attribute?

Comment: Instances inherit attributes from the class, it doesn't go the other way.

Comment: Because the class object doesn't have that attribute. Why did you think it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful `cls` is typically used for `classmethod`s for example like this:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    @classmethod
    def fromBirthYear(cls, name, birthYear):
        return cls(name, date.today().year - birthYear)
```

So it is better to not use it for your own class names to avoid confusion.

Comming to your question.
In your first block you use a reference to the class itself. So here only static variables are visible as `__init__` has not been called.

```
>>> print(hasattr(cls1,'A'))
True
>>> print(hasattr(cls1,'a'))
False
```

In the second block you use an instance of the class. Here, `__init__()` was executed and therefore `obj.a` exists.

```
>>> obj=cls1()
>>> print(hasattr(obj,'A'))
True
>>> print(hasattr(obj,'a'))
True
```

Comment: `cls` is **not** a [keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok let me reword it, it is typically used for cassmethods and should thus not be used as variabel to avoid confusion...

Comment: You're very welcome to reword it, you can [edit] your post.